# Send data to server and handle response - Android

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-json, android-webservice

I'm trying to post data to a [this](http://grpsvil.si2001.it/APIClient/Contents/RestPartnerTest.aspx) webservice, but seems I cannot get this right! So Im trying to post json to the server but I dont know how to do that. I need to send this example json in order to get a json responce:

> Content-Type : application/json HTTPMethod : POST HTTPBody :
>   {"CouponVerificationCode":"594952223490","ApiKey":"zFyWQDYUKXQQpvG86snPD1OSslr7Q6DGEGbQ1f7P2YeTxB56y","Token":"_2_jx1YFvTZGGLNtJBoDW3gDZmNNAGpTWzT7dC6GrNAIkhhX9PWv75b776gq1ZO_2_SxMJjq8_2_kaDMyxX59HczOyaw=="}

but instead of getting a json responce i get html responce. 
Can someone please help me solve this issue?

This is the code im using to communicate with the server:

```
public static String makeRequest(String path) throws Exception {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(path);
        JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
        // holder.accumulate(name, value)


        String test = "{\"ApiKey\":\"somekey\","
                + "\"OperativeSystem\":\"0\","
                + "\"AppVersion\":\"1\","
                + "\"WebServiceVersion\":\"1\"}";
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(test);
        Log.v("--", test);
        httpost.setEntity(se);
        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
        // HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Log.v("--", response);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: You need to parse the responce convert it to string

Comment: @geekCode the responce is html not json

Comment: what is the answer you are getting right now..??

Comment: You sure that's the correct url and it accepts json data?? I used to fiddler to trace the request sent when you fill in the details at the provided url. And its posting form data not Json. Please provide the correct url.

Comment: @geekCode http://pastebin.com/9MNzKypS

Comment: @Gaurav that is the url that is provided to me, do you think maybe the url is wrong?

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski - You need to confirm the following combination url ,request type,request content type. If one of them isn't right you won't be able to hit the webservice correctly.

Comment: and also there is no data posted...

Answer (score 0):

Try Using httpGet instead of httpPost. here is my working code:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpGet httpGet =new HttpGet(url);
            String User =  context.getString(R.string.json_uname);
            String Password =  context.getString(R.string.json_pwd);
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ new String(Base64.encode((User +":"+ Password).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP )));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
            {
                //convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String json = reader.readLine();
                JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
                 finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
            }
            else
                 finalResult =null;
```